# Which Tool can generate UML by SQL?

Tags: sql, uml, diagram

I'm searching a tool for generating UML-Diagrams by the import of SQL-Syntax-Files.

I need it for personal usage. Best if it's free or if there is a free trial license available.

Comment: Which UML diagrams? A class diagram?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will do it directly from a SQL file as I've never tried it that way, but Enterprise Architect will connect directly to a database and create the schema diagram automatically.  My guess would be that it could do it directly from a file, but again I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: what DBMS do you use? if you are using sql server, then you can just generate the database diagram in the sql server management studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL-Syntax is provided by

- Data Manipulation Language (DML) select,insert,update..
- Data Definition Language (DDL) create table,..
- Data Control Language (DCL) grant,revoke

The closest thing you can map to UML are tables to classes (DDL).

[Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) among other UML tools offers reverse engineering of existing database schema

Answer (score 1):

If you just need database structure diagrams (entity relationship diagrams), Visio has a nice way to connect to a database and generate an ERD from the schema.  If you are looking for a class diagram, you can use Visual Studio 2010 to create entity framework objects from a database and will give you a few different ways to represent them (either in the entity framework GUI designer, or by creating a class diagram from the generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerDesigner by Sybase](http://www.powerdesigner.de/en) allows you reverse DB from script (so called Physical model) and after all convert it to another diagram including UML object model

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to generate a java code from your database then to reverse the code within an UML tool. A good Eclipse project is Dali which can generate an annoted code (e.g. @Entity) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL diagram tool is not an UML tool but a database modeler !! UML requires object mapping with relational database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a IBM rational rose software is not freeware but this is the best software engineering tools for UML to SQL database.  It does so many interesting things so try to work on IBM rational rose.

That you can download from [Download  -  Rational Rose](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rose/)